# Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ´ (U+00B4)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

I just started using LaTeX (with texstudio). I have never worked on LaTeX before. I faced this error and I don't know how to solve it. I tried to look at this website (tex.stackexchange). There are some questions related to my error but I couldn't solve my problem using similar methods.

I also have another similar error that includes a vertical barcode image (I couldn't paste the image here)(U+00B4).

I found some answers mentioning preamble but I don't know what it is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Did you copy some text containing an [accent character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b4/index.htm)? If so, remove the word and type it in by hand.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What about the vertical copyright image?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean with vertical  copyright image. Please explain in more detail by editing the question.

Comment: I tried to search on google with U+0092 code, it showed "Unicode Character 'PRIVATE USE TWO' (U+0092)" this character. But on my screen the image is different.

Comment: Hey, I solved using the same step which you told me earlier. Thanks so much.